# magento 2 : how to add excel formate validation in the input?

Tags: magento2, frontend, validation

CSV validation working fine in existing code, so how to add excel formate in that validation

**phtml code:-**

```
<input data-validate="{required:false, 'validate-custom-file-csv':true}" type="file" name="file" data-reset="true" id="sku_csv" class="upload" value="">
```

When I upload another formate file, I got message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFEyY.png

already js file commented link this layout file

**drop your suggestion and answer**

Answer (score 0):

You need to search in the code base with the `validate-custom-file-csv` in any of the files inside of js code you will be able to see code that logic will be checking file type. So you can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

`'validate-custom-file-csv':true` is custom create validation or Magento 2 provide it?

Because I cannot find it in the rule list: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/validations/rule-list.html

Now I am assuming that you have created this validation using JS there you are just validating for `.csv` if you want an excel file to get uploaded then you need to do some changes or create a new one for example `validate-custom-allowed-file` and replace it with existing one

Thanks